# Combine two Observables, but only when the first obs is immediately preceded by the second

Tags: c#, system.reactive

My goal is probably easiest explained with a marble diagram.
I have two Observables, xs and ys.  I want to return a Observable named rs.

```
xs --x---x---x---x-------x---x---x-
      \           \       \
ys ----y-----------y---y---y-------
       |           |       |
rs ----x-----------x-------x-------
       y           y       y
```

So, I need something similar to CombineLatest, except it should only fire when an xs is followed by a ys.  Additional xs's or ys's outside of that pattern should not trigger an output and should be discarded.

CombineLatest, Zip, or And/Then/When don't do what I need and I can't find any way to specify a more complicated join structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using Join.

```
var rs = xs.Join(ys, 
                 _ => xs.Merge(ys),
                 _ => Observable.Empty<Unit>(),
                 Tuple.Create);
```

This is a good article that explains how Join works:
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2012/04/04/rx-join.aspx

Answer (score 3):

For questions like these it is really useful to provide a test scenario. You have given a great little marble diagram of what you want, it is really easy to then convert that to a test case. Then other forum readers can just grab the test code, implement their idea and know if they are meeting your requirements or not.

```
[Test]
public void Should_only_get_latest_value_from_Y_but_not_while_x_produes()
{
    //            11111111112222222222333
    //   12345678901234567890123456789012
    //xs --x---x---x---x-------x---x---x-
    //      \           \       \
    //ys ----y-----------y---y---y-------
    //       |           |       |
    //rs ----x-----------x-------x-------
    //       y           y       y


    var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
    //            11111111112222222222333
    //   12345678901234567890123456789012
    //xs --x---x---x---x-------x---x---x-
    var xs = testScheduler.CreateColdObservable(
        new Recorded<Notification<char>>(3, Notification.CreateOnNext('1')),
        new Recorded<Notification<char>>(7, Notification.CreateOnNext('2')),
        new Recorded<Notification<char>>(10, Notification.CreateOnNext('3')),
        new Recorded<Notification<char>>(15, Notification.CreateOnNext('4')),
        new Recorded<Notification<char>>(23, Notification.CreateOnNext('5')),
        new Recorded<Notification<char>>(27, Notification.CreateOnNext('6')),
        new Recorded<Notification<char>>(31, Notification.CreateOnNext('7')));

    //            11111111112222222222333
    //   12345678901234567890123456789012
    //ys ----y-----------y---y---y-------
    var ys = testScheduler.CreateColdObservable(
        new Recorded<Notification<char>>(5, Notification.CreateOnNext('A')),
        new Recorded<Notification<char>>(17, Notification.CreateOnNext('B')),
        new Recorded<Notification<char>>(21, Notification.CreateOnNext('C')),
        new Recorded<Notification<char>>(25, Notification.CreateOnNext('D')));


    //Expected :
    //Tick  x   y
    //5     1   A
    //17    4   B
    //25    5   D
    var expected = new[]
    {
        new Recorded<Notification<Tuple<char, char>>>(5, Notification.CreateOnNext(Tuple.Create('1', 'A'))),
        new Recorded<Notification<Tuple<char, char>>>(17, Notification.CreateOnNext(Tuple.Create('4', 'B'))),
        new Recorded<Notification<Tuple<char, char>>>(25, Notification.CreateOnNext(Tuple.Create('5', 'D')))
    };

    var observer = testScheduler.CreateObserver<Tuple<char, char>>();

    //Passes HOT, fails Cold. Doesn't meet the requirements due to Timeout anyway.
    //xs.Select(x => ys.Take(1)
    //                    .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5),
    //                            Observable.Empty<char>())
    //                    .Select(y => Tuple.Create(x, y))
    //    )
    //    .Switch()
    //    .Subscribe(observer);

    //Passes HOT. Passes Cold
    xs.Join(ys,
            _ => xs.Merge(ys),
            _ => Observable.Empty<Unit>(),
            Tuple.Create)
        .Subscribe(observer);

    testScheduler.Start();

    //You may want to Console.WriteLine out the two collections to validate for yourself.

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, observer.Messages);
}
```

P.S. Great usage of Merge for the answer by the way.

Comment: Use the `OnNext` method in `ReactiveTest` to avoid repeating `new Recorded<Notification<char>>`

Answer (score 0):

To state the diagram another way, each x needs to *take the first* y *without an additional x before the y*.  Those first requirement suggests `Take(1)`.  At that point, you will have an `IObservable<IObservable<...>>`.  The second requirement and the type generated by the first two points to `Switch`.  Putting it all together, you should be able to match the diagram with:

```
var rs = xs.Select(x => ys.Take(1)
                          .Select(y => Tuple.Create(x, y))
                  )
           .Switch()
```

Comment: The timing of these events are not regular, so I can't use a Timeout.  But I could merge ys and xs, Take(1), then filter out the cases where I have two values from xs.  Its not pretty, I will need to add type information to xs and ys, but it should work.

Comment: The way this works looks similar to a Window. I wonder if I can make something a bit more elegant with that.

Comment: @oillio: I suggest you add that as an answer to your question :)

Comment: Hey I voted down because of the timeout. It is not the right answer IMO.

Comment: @LeeCampbell You're right. For some reason I initially read the question as stating y's had to come close to x's.  Upon further review, there is no such timing requirement, so the Timeout is not correct.